# Which is the syntax of SESSION ID

Tags: html-parsing, jsessionid

I'm making a web crawler with python and I sometimes find ":jsessionid=XXXX" in urls. I have made a function to delete it. My function takes an url and deletes from it the pattern ";jsession=XXXX...", where "XXXX..." is a pattern that matches anything till a question mark. I'm not sure if the algorithm is correct, because I don't get the syntax of jsessionid="...".
Anyway, my function is the following, could you please tell me if it's correct or where I can find the syntax of SESSION ID?

```
def deleteJSessionid(link):
    print("originalLink:",link)
    p = re.compile(r';jsessionid=[^?]*',re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
    p = p.search(link)
    print("\n\n"+p.group()+"\n\n")
    start = p.span()[0]
    end = p.span()[1]
    link = link[:start] + link[end:]
    return link
```

Comment: Do you have a full example URL?

Comment: http://trasparenza.regione.piemonte.it/amministrazione-trasparente;jsessionid=FA49D28EFAB069F960B62DC20FA0F3EC

Comment: I don't have many examples...

Comment: Actually, there is no defined format/syntax for session IDs in URLs. There are many ways to encode that ID into an URL and many of them are used. "jsessionid", for example, is only the default setting on some JEE servers; it can be configured freely and other server technologies use other names/means, like plain old "GET" parameters. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID, or the PHP manual for instance.